# Compute distance in grid to find service area

Tags: python

I am trying to assess the potential of Python to calculate the service area of two points.

The idea is to create a map showing which terminal is more efficient in serving a given cell based in distance or cost or time (different map for each).

The image shows point A and point B as terminals, I am trying to calculate the service area (or influence area) for each of the terminals.

In the example on the right the domain is homogeneous, and in the example on the left we have rail (green) and waterway (yellow). The different transportation modes will change the cost and time to market of any shipment to/from A and B. Intermodal operations are possible when any of the modes intercept i.e. green to white, white to yellow, yellow to green, etc.

By service area I mean a given cell is closer/cheaper/faster to a A or to B. Once I have this information than I´d be able to create a service area map of A and B.

My question is if python is the right tool for this. As you might notice I am not familiar with programming and would appreciate any tips (tutorials, etc).

Please feel free to ask any questions back if the problem description is not clear.

Domain of the problem:

[image]

Comment: Python is a Turing complete language, and as such, probably suited for the job.

Comment: At the same time, Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site. Please see the page https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get a sense of the types of questions that are expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem in almost any programming language.

Python is a high-level programming language, meaning it takes care of things like memory management. This makes it somewhat slower but easier to learn as you have to write fewer lines of code to do what you want.

It is also versatile, well supported and established, making it a good candidate for a first language.

However, ultimately, the question is what you are going to do with it? For example, if you want to develop something for the web, then going with JavaScript is probably better.

Here a rough guide where different programming languages are used
[image]

Otherwise google "which programming language should I learn" to find any of millions of articles on this topic.